# PhpStorm with flowtype doesn't recognise React.Node

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, webstorm, flowtype

My PhpStorm doesn't recognize flowtype React.Node. I got `Unresolved variable Node`.

I know it is only a warning and Flow works fine without any errors but it is still a little annoying.

I use `flow-bin: 0.72.0` and `react: 16.2.0`

Do you guys know how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow [WEB-32941](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-32941) for updates